# How to store the filePath from FileChooser?

Tags: kotlin, user-interface, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am trying to develop an Intellij Idea plugin. To open a dialog box I have used FileChooser. I was able to see the files but how do I store that filePath after selecting the file to use it further ?
Here's my code

```
 val fileChooser = FileChooserDescriptor(true,
                false,
                false,
                false,
                false,
                false)
        fileChooser.title = "Choose the files"
        fileChooser.description = "Choose the files"
        FileChooser.chooseFile(fileChooser, e.project, null)
```

If possible please provide a documentation link which I can refer to since I am new to Kotlin & Intellij Idea plugin development.

Comment: `FileChooser.chooseFile()` returns the file chosen, doesn't it?

Comment: How do I use the returned file ?

Comment: What do you want to do with it?